# SQL query working with 8.0 but not working with 5.7

Tags: mysql, optimization, query, mysql-5.7

I have a mysql table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `users_search_activity` (
  `ID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `search_keywords` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users_search_activity`
--

INSERT INTO `users_search_activity` (`ID`, `user_id`, `country_id`, `search_keywords`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 132, 2, 'xavie', '2021-07-13 08:20:37'),
(2, 132, 6, 'xavier', '2021-07-13 08:21:38'),
(3, 132, 5, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 08:21:39'),
(4, 132, 4, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 08:21:39'),
(5, 131, 9, 'xavier ins',  '2021-07-13 08:22:12'),
(6, 132, 7, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 08:22:25'),
(7, 132, 8, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:43'),
(8, 132, 6, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:45'),
(9, 132, 4, 'xavier insa', '2021-07-13 09:24:47'),
(10, 131, 5, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:54'),
(11, 132, 3, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:54'),
(12, 132, 2, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:58'),
(13, 132, 9, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:59'),
(14, 132, 0, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:25:00'),
(15, 132, 0, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:25:02'),
(16, 132, 0, 'inst', '2021-07-13 09:58:20'),
(17, 132, 0, 'inst', '2021-07-04 09:58:25'),
(18, 132, 0, 'inst', '2021-07-07 09:58:25'),
(19, 132, 0, 'inst', '2021-07-11 09:58:26'),
(20, 1, 12, 'University Business Academy in Novi Sad', '2021-07-14 10:16:33');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `users_search_activity`
--
ALTER TABLE `users_search_activity`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users_search_activity`
--
ALTER TABLE `users_search_activity`
  MODIFY `ID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=20;
COMMIT;
```

To get the search keywords separated by comma group by country_id and user_id I have used this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY country_id) AS 
count, user_id, country_id, DATE(date) as date, 
group_concat(search_keywords) as search_keywords 
 FROM users_search_activity group by country_id
```

Its working absolutely fine but only with mySQL 8+ version and doesn't work with 5.7. So can someone tell me how to make this query to run with 5.7?

Any help and suggestions would be really appreciable.

**FYI**: Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb861631b1dc1ddbe0ae86b8fcc0a31c).

Comment: The above query gives the exact desired result what I want. Only thing is its not working with MySQL 5.7

Comment: As Ergest Basha told you, window functions were introduced on MySQL 8. You cannot use `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY country_id)` on MySQL 5.7

Comment: So is there any alternate function for 5.7 which I can use and get the desired result what I am getting with 8.0?

Comment: (Unrelated:  Suggest adding `DISTINCT` in the `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what your query returns when I test it on MySQL 8.0:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY country_id) AS  count, user_id, country_id, DATE(date) as date,  group_concat(search_keywords) as search_keywords   FROM users_search_activity group by country_id;
+-------+---------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+
| count | user_id | country_id | date       | search_keywords                         |
+-------+---------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+
|     1 |     132 |          0 | 2021-07-11 | inst,inst,inst,inst,ins,ins             |
|     1 |     132 |          2 | 2021-07-13 | xavie,ins                               |
|     1 |     132 |          3 | 2021-07-13 | ins                                     |
|     1 |     132 |          4 | 2021-07-13 | xavier ins,xavier insa                  |
|     1 |     132 |          5 | 2021-07-13 | xavier ins,ins                          |
|     1 |     132 |          6 | 2021-07-13 | xavier,xavier ins                       |
|     1 |     132 |          7 | 2021-07-13 | xavier ins                              |
|     1 |     132 |          8 | 2021-07-13 | xavier ins                              |
|     1 |     132 |          9 | 2021-07-13 | ins,xavier ins                          |
|     1 |       1 |         12 | 2021-07-14 | University Business Academy in Novi Sad |
+-------+---------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Why is the count always 1? Because you have both a `GROUP BY country_id` clause and a window function. Naturally after the grouping has been done, there is one row per country_id. So when you partition by country_id, the count of each partition is 1.

You probably want the following:

```
mysql> select count(*), user_id, country_id, DATE(date), group_concat(search_keywords) as search_keywords from users_search_activity group by country_id;
+----------+---------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+
| count(*) | user_id | country_id | DATE(date) | search_keywords                         |
+----------+---------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+
|        6 |     132 |          0 | 2021-07-11 | inst,inst,inst,inst,ins,ins             |
|        2 |     132 |          2 | 2021-07-13 | xavie,ins                               |
|        1 |     132 |          3 | 2021-07-13 | ins                                     |
|        2 |     132 |          4 | 2021-07-13 | xavier ins,xavier insa                  |
|        2 |     132 |          5 | 2021-07-13 | xavier ins,ins                          |
|        2 |     132 |          6 | 2021-07-13 | xavier,xavier ins                       |
|        1 |     132 |          7 | 2021-07-13 | xavier ins                              |
|        1 |     132 |          8 | 2021-07-13 | xavier ins                              |
|        2 |     132 |          9 | 2021-07-13 | ins,xavier ins                          |
|        1 |       1 |         12 | 2021-07-14 | University Business Academy in Novi Sad |
+----------+---------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

This uses an aggregate function COUNT(*) without a window function, so it counts the number of rows in the group, not the number of rows *after* applying the GROUP BY.

The latter query works on MySQL 5.7, since it contains no syntax that requires a later version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When using this query on 5.7 I am getting this error

`Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db_289283206.users_search_activity.user_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html